# accept only alphabets and numbers. Replace others by single '-'. PHP

Tags: php, regex, slug

In my code, I have a function for remove all `non-alphabetic` and `non-numeric` characters with a '-'. But the problem is my `regex` just removing the special character what evre it is with '-'. So if the input is

```
((hai..)how   are you?)
```

will change as

```
--hai---how---are-you--
```

I need to combine all adjacent '-' as one.And remove the starting and ending special characters. that is the above result become

```
 hai-how-are-you
```

my function is

```
function to_slug($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    return $string1 = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string)));
}
```

and i got a regex code for combine the '-'.

```
trim(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str), '-')
```

But i don't know how to combine this. Please help.. Thank you in advance

Comment: why not just replace with `''` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function toSlug($string){
    $string = trim($string);
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9a-z]+)/i', '-', $string), '-'));
}
```

Comment: thank for it.. but it only removes the leading and trailing ones. `hai---how---are-you`. I also need to join the in-between '-'s

Comment: @Arun I'm sorry, I forgot a `+`, and I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want,

```
<?php
$string = '((hai..)how   are you?)';
$pattern = '~[^a-z0-9]+~';
$replacement = '-';
$str1 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
$pat = '~^-+|-+$~';
$rep = '';
echo preg_replace($pat, $rep, $str1);
?> //=> hai-how-are-you
```

Answer (score 1):

use the flag `g`:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g
```

it'll match **multiple non-alphanumeric characters** and replace them with one `-`. i.e.

`((`hai`..)`how   are you`?)` will be replaced with `-`hai`-`how`-`are`-`you`-`

[HERE is the demo](http://regex101.com/r/qZ3eD5/1)

probably with `trim(`, as in the above answer above, it'll remove the trailing / leading `-` as well